# placeholder error in django cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django-cms to design a cms site,i had configured everything and working fine.but when i tried to use `placeholder` tag, its displaying errors

suppose i had the **base.html** code as below

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Welcome to Services</title>
</head>
<body>
   {% cms_toolbar %}
   <div class='new'> 
      {% block base_content %}{% endblock %} 
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And i am trying to render **home.html** with below code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
  {% placeholder 'terms_and_conditions' %}
     <p>This is the placeholder of editing the data</p>
  {% endplaceholder %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the below errors when i refresh the page

```
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'endplaceholder', expected 'endblock'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 320
```

Can anyone please let me know whats wrong in the above html code and how to solve the above error

### Edited

Also when i uncommented `admin.autodiscover()` in urls.py i am getting a weird error as below

```
Exception Value:  cannot import name plugin_pool
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/admin/__init__.py in <module>, line 7
```

And when i accessed the url `http://localhost:8000/admin/`, its displaying

```
"You had no permissions to edit anything"
```

**Edited2**

Also i am not getting/unable to see editable mode even though after adding `{% cms_toolbar %}` in `body tag`

Comment: try `{% placeholder 'terms_and_conditions' or %} ... {% endplaceholder %}`

Comment: yeah i tried, its displaying nothing .... Actually a paragraph needs to be displayed and it should be editable right ?

Comment: @DanielB:I have edited my code above and added some extra content, can u please look over and help me out here ?

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://localhost:8000/?edit` ?

Comment: Its returning to basic home page

Answer (score 0):

remove   {% endplaceholder %}

There is no such tag as a endplaceholder as specified in your error log

Invalid block tag: 'endplaceholder', expected 'endblock'